# appending pytorch object in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pytorch

I want to append tensor objects c, s in empty dataframe df_data1_cluster

```
df_data1_cluster = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["cluster", "text"])

label, center = detect_clusters(torch.as_tensor(embeddings), 50)
for c, s in zip(label, phrases):
    df_data1_cluster.append(c,s)
```

It is resulting in error.

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'torch.Tensor'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

Comment: convert tensor to list?

Comment: It is also producing error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [112], in <cell line: 4>()
      3 label, center = detect_clusters(torch.as_tensor(embeddings), 50)
      4 for c, s in zip(label, phrases):
----> 5     df_data1_cluster.append(list(c),list(s))


TypeError: iteration over a 0-d tensor

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is a pandas problem, the append command requires u append a dataframe, there are ways to insert to a dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
import torch

df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [1, 2, 3], 'colors': ['red', 'white', 'blue']})
df['numbers'].loc[-1] = torch.tensor([2, 3, 4])  # adding a row
```

Comment: please look up on various methods to insert to a dataframe